# How to join objects on an already weight painted object?

Tags: objects, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I created a shoe in Blender and I already rigged it and made vertex groups. I now plan to add more details on the shoe. I tried to join all the objects together, but the other objects I joined to the shoe didn't want to go with the bones. I wanted to weight paint the details but it completely deformed them. Do you have a solution for me?[image][image][image]

Comment: Hello, please give more informations, show pictures or even share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Okay I'll do it.

Comment: if it's too hard in Weight Paint mode you can select the vertices, go into the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, then assign to the vertex the vertex group they are supposed to be part of

Comment: You also don't have to join them. You can have two seperate objects assgined to the same armature. Just in case you didn't know.

Comment: I did it, but the ring got smaller and is in a completely different position afterwards. I would like the ring to bend as much as the shoe and stay in the same position. Is it possible that I copy the vertex groups from the shoe to the ring so that it bends in the same way?